# MySQL SELECT COUNT(1) statement too slow on table with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata, query-optimization

The following statement takes 0.73 seconds and generates 54,000 results:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country) AGAINST(' +Germany' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This statement takes 28 seconds and generates 3.3 millions results:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country) AGAINST(' +United +States' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Is there a way to limit the query time by somehow capping the results at one million?

Something like this:

```
COUNT THIS -->    
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country) AGAINST(' +United +States' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Wrap your select query in this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ( ... ) as someRandomWord
```

My select query is altered to this so that results can be limited:

```
SELECT counter FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, experience, country) AGAINST(' +United +States' IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 1000000
```

Put this two together:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
SELECT counter FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, experience, country) AGAINST(' +business' IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 1000000
) as someRandomWord
```

"Germany" --> 54,000 results (0.76 seconds)

"United States" ---> "More than one million results" (2.4 seconds)

Comment: OMG it muse be EXISTS, not count!

Comment: Now run the original count again.  It may run fast, but due to caching.

Answer (score -1):

You should run explain plan and find your inefficiencies.  You can see how to analyze explain plain at this article:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html
Key points:

1. Your goals are to recognize the aspects of the EXPLAIN plan that indicate a query is optimized well, and to learn the SQL syntax and indexing techniques to improve the plan if you see some inefficient operations.
2. With the help of EXPLAIN, you can see where you should add indexes to tables so that the statement executes faster by using indexes to find rows
3. You can also use EXPLAIN to check whether the optimizer joins the tables in an optimal order.
4. The EXPLAIN statement provides information about how MySQL executes statements. EXPLAIN works with SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE statements.

Based on your SQL it appears your using MySQL.

The end result might be to add indexes. This article should help to create your indexes:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm
Key Points:

1. Creating indexes speed up access data but uses disk space to maintain the index. Here is how you can create an index: `CREATE INDEX AUTHOR_INDEX ON tutorials_tbl (tutorial_author DESC)`
2. DESC/ASC - You should think about the natural order of data and order based on the most likely way you want to access it. If it was timeseries and you most always want to the most recent data, the use DESC order.

Comment: Please include the essential parts you find in the links, link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or shutdown.

Comment: I'ved updated with additional commentary. Thank you for pointing this out.